# Server went down due to many request

Tags: server, hosting, web-hosting

I am planning to make an e-commerce website but I am searching now the possible issues before doing it. For example, once I deployed my site in the hosting server and the number of costumers will have access to the site is about 300k per day. My question is:

1. Is it possible that my server will go down because of the huge people accessing it per day?
2. What are the possible issues why it will go down and what are the things I have to consider to prevent it from happening?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, if number of users accessing the server exceed the bandwith it will go down due heavy traffic.
2. First of all best solution to this is building a horizontal scalable model which means if you encounter this kind of "bottleneck" issues, you can upgrade the hardware or add more servers.

There are plenty ways to prevent this to happening, away from upgrading hardware you may consider reducing DB queries too, there are lot of factors that effects overloading.

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course yes, many users come to your site can make your server become unstable. It depends on the server that you use, how much RAM installed and also server specifications.
2. If you believe it was because traffic to your site, then the option is to upgrade your hardware. Without upgrading your server, your site will always go down.